# No se puede insertar un valor explícito en la columna de identidad de la tabla

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando el proceso que almacenar datos de un form a una tabla de sql, la estructura de mi tabla es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El evento del button `guardar`:

```
protected void ButtonGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calificar_proveedor calificar_proveedor = new calificar_proveedor();

            var idtecer = LabelIdentificacion.Text;

            string sql = "SELECT id_tercero from tercero WHERE nro_identificacion=@idtecer";
            var registro = db.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>(sql, new SqlParameter("@idtecer", idtecer)).SingleOrDefault();

            calificar_proveedor.id_tercero_proveedor = Convert.ToDecimal(registro);
            calificar_proveedor.certIso = Convert.ToDecimal(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
            calificar_proveedor.flexPago = Convert.ToDecimal(DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
            calificar_proveedor.condMercadeo = Convert.ToDecimal(DropDownList3.SelectedValue);

calificar_proveedor = db.calificar_proveedor.Add(calificar_proveedor);
            db.SaveChanges();
}
```

sucede que me genera el siguiente error:
`{"No se puede insertar un valor explícito en la columna de identidad de la tabla 'calificar_proveedor' cuando IDENTITY_INSERT es OFF."}
Aspx/Compras/calificarProveedor.aspx`

es claro y lo entiendo, que no se puede insertar un dato en un campo identidad de la tabla, al hacer la validacion con puntos de interrupcion verifico que a ese campo se esta enviando un valor `0` por defecto, considero que desde la query, mi pregunta es como modifico la query de forma que no me tome ese valor cero por defecto y pueda guardar la informacion.

por cierto este es el modelo

```
public partial class calificar_proveedor
    {
        [Key]
        public decimal id_calificar_proveedor { get; set; }
        public decimal id_tercero_proveedor { get; set; }
        public decimal certIso { get; set; }
        public decimal flexPago { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Estas usando EF? que tiene que ver el codigo que pusiste (que es un select) con tu error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu modelo tienes que usar el atributo "DatabaseGenerated" en la propiedad id_calificar_proveedor

```
public partial class calificar_proveedor
{
    [Key][DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public decimal id_calificar_proveedor { get; set; }
    public decimal id_tercero_proveedor { get; set; }
    public decimal certIso { get; set; }
    public decimal flexPago { get; set; }
}
```